# Should a PDO object be passed to classes and procedural functions as a parameter?

Tags: php, pdo

I've been trying to figure out the best way to manage database connections for a while now and am still unsure of how I should be doing things. I know there are a lot of similar questions on here, but I've read many of them and am still confused.

Some answers on here say singletons should be used, but it seems a larger percentage of answers say *not* to use singletons because they make debugging much harder.

My current method is to create a PDO object and then pass it as a parameter:

```
/**
 * Creates and returns PDO object
 *
 * @return PDO
 */
function createPDO() {
    // MySQL connection
    $dbUser = '';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbName = '';

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        errorHandler(0, $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), print_r($e, true), 'sql');
        die('SQL Error, terminating script.');
    }

    return $db;
}

/**
 * Makes a PDO query
 *
 * @param @var $stmt The PDO statement
 * @param array $array The array of PDO statement parameters
 */
function makeQuery($stmt, $array) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute($array);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        errorHandler(0, $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), print_r($e, true), 'sql');
        die('SQL Error, terminating script.');
    }
}
```

Then in my scripts I'll use the object like this:

```
$db = createPDO();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ....')
makeQuery($stmt, array(':boundParameter' => '..'));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If I instantiate new classes, or call procedural functions, I pass `$db` as a parameter:

```
$myClass = new myClass($db);
```

Is this a good way of doing things, or is there a better way?

Comment: [A long but outstanding read on the subject is here](http://kunststube.net/static/).  Basically, you should be passing it in because (1) it will make your application architecture easier to understand, (2) it will help keep your code decoupled, and (3) most testing frameworks out there expect this behavior.

Comment: I like convention, and that means use default connection provided by singleton unless told otherwise. So I would use just `$myClass = new myClass($db);`, and if other connection but the default should be used: `$myClass->setConnection($db)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the review, and then talk about correctness of the approach.

- **Pass things by parameters** - What do you do if your credentials change? Don't you want to reuse the function? Pass the credentials as parameters to the `createPDO` function, or better yet, the DSN directly:

  ```
  function createPDO($dsn, $user, $password)
  ```
- **Add good practice defaults to PDO instance** - Use `$pdo->setAttribute()` to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false`.
- **Don't handle exceptions in your function** - You are creating hidden dependencies (You now depend on `errorHandler` to exist somewhere in your application). Also, you don't know what you want to do if you fail creating the PDO instance. In this app you may want to kill the script, in another you may want to fall back to the filesystem. **It's not your function's job to know!**
- **Typehint what you can** - Your `$stmt` variable is a `PDOStatement` object. You should hint it in the function's signature. Your `$array` is an array.

  ```
  function makeQuery(PDOStatement $stmt, array $params)
  ```

---

Approach wise, you should ask yourself, **What in my application needs a PDO object?**

If the rest of your application is procedural, there's no point in even what little abstraction you tried to give here. However, if you do have some sort of other object which uses the PDO connection, then using **lazy loading** is a good practice to follow:

```
$pdoProvider = function() {
    //Do all PDO instantiation logic here
};
$mapperFactory = new MapperFactory($pdoProvider);
```

By passing in a *function* instead of *the actual object*, you can delay the creation of the object until it's first needed (which may not even happen, saving you the connection!)

In the MapperFactory:

```
class MapperFactory {
    private $provider;
    private $pdoInstance;
    public function __construct(callable $provider) {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }
    public function create($mapper) {
        if ($this->pdoInstance !instanceof PDO) {
            $this->pdoInstance = call_user_func($this->provider); //Call the provider, get the PDO instance
        }
        //By this point, $this->pdoInstance has a PDO instance for sure.
    }
}
```

For more information, See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/871050)** on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I find it really annoying to pass in the database object every time I instantiate a class. Instead, you could just create a database class with static methods. Then in all your functions you can just simply use `database::getInstance()` to get the database object. Further more, it prevents you from connecting multiple times.

```
class database {

    public static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {

        if(!self::$instance) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                errorHandler(0, $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), print_r($e, true), 'sql');
                die('SQL Error, terminating script.');
            }
        }

        return self::$instance;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you do that (composition) you can't change it at runtime very easily without it getting messy. What if you want that class to connect to a different database (because you've started sharding)? If you insist on using the singleton style pattern, at least use named instances so you can select a different db (still not as nice or flexible as aggregation though i.e. passing in the db object)

Comment: That's called a Singleton and it's an [anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)